# Emulating this curl code on android

Tags: java, php, android, curl

I have a script that is written in PHP but I need to make it into an android app. How do I get the same result?

```
$url = "http://54.193.106.113/ING004/android1/WebServer/Web/sogame/newControl/nmMail/getMailList?    sign=".strtoupper($sign);

$connection = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $finalData);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

$result = curl_exec($connection);

$err = curl_error($connection);

$baseObj = json_decode($result, true);  

curl_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am admittedly new to the world of Android, but it looks like what you're trying to do is an HTTP request that returns a collection of data (e.g. a list of emails on a mailing list).  I've implemented similar functionality (just not with Android) and I would strongly suggest looking into something at least a little cleaner for your URL structure (google REST URLs).

That said, here are a few things I've found that hopefully will help you:

[Make an HTTP Request with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

[Article on integrating a REST API into Android](http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, this may be just what I need. Thank you!